# Sip client raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, sip

I am trying to make a call with video and audio using sip client. I have tried twinkle but it does not support video call, I also tried linphone using the given python code but I didn't make it work. Does any one has a sample or know some other sip clients that support audio and video?

I have used this command for twinkle

```
sudo apt-get install twinkle
```

Comment: Can you give more information on why linphone doesn't work?

Comment: i call my desktop pc that has xlite client, i have sound but not video

Comment: This is too broad and asking for software recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Zoiper](http://www.zoiper.com/en)? It supports video and uses SIP. It runs on Linux too, although it might be a bit too much for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: i downloaded it and tried to run but it says cannot run binary file

Comment: @PanayiotisIrakleous Hmm. I just remembered the Pi is ARM not x86 or x64. My mistake there.